# FirefoxDriver don't use my Proxy (geckodriver)

Tags: java, http-proxy, geckodriver

I created this code and I already fixed the Problem that its not connecting to any website, (it was like opening the firefox browser but not opening any website which i wanted).

My current Problem is that it not uses the given Proxy.

```java
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\michi\\Desktop\\insta\\geckodriver\\geckodriver.exe");

String proxy = "88.118.134.214:60737"; //got this from public proxy list
String[] split = proxy.split(":");
String proxy_ip = split[0];
String proxy_port = split[1];

FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http", proxy_ip);
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http_port", proxy_port);

DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
dc.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(dc);
driver.get("https://www.wieistmeineip.de/");

Thread.sleep(5000);
driver.quit();
```

Does anybody now how to fix this? Should i use an other WebDriver or smth?

Thank you in advance!